# Persistence Framework for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, persistence, devforce

Besides the framework from [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/persistence-framework.aspx#Overview), what other persistence frameworks exist for Silverlight?

Comment: Do you mean beyond the built-in IsolatedStorage mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideablade does.  Architected by Ward Bell.  http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/

http://www.ideablade.com/index.html

Link directly to their Silverlight DevForce page:

http://www.ideablade.com/DevForceSilverlight/DevForceSilverlight_overview.aspx

Comment: Isn't that just for WPF or am I mistaken?

Comment: You're mistaken. Their website lists both WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: Added a link to their DevForce Silverlight page.